# Error: "Email: data value too large: (max length=80)"

Tags: error

When migrating contact record to Salesforce I hit this error: "Email: data value too large: (max length=80)".

What should I do if one of my emails is longer than 80 characters?

Answer (score 4):

You are stuck -- You'll need to get aliases created for these emails before they can go into Contact.email.

As a workaround for the hopefully 99% valid (<=80 char email) contacts, 
You could import the 'email' field to a custom field: `Contact.imported_email__c` and then use workflows to copy that to Contact.email if length <=80

Then, the too long emails could be dealt with later.

Note Idea  - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpGHAA0 where PM (admittedly 5 years ago) says that SFDC can't reliably deliver to email addresses longer than 80 chars

Of course, SFDC itself generates inbound email service addresses that are way longer than 80 characters so they obviously expect other MTAs to be able to send such emails.

Comment: Interestingly the addresses for apex email services are reliably greater than 80 characters.

Comment: URL fields are also similarly limited. You can have arbitrarily long URLs, but salesforce.com can't store them.

Comment: Per IETF, the valid emails are limited to 254 chars. Maybe Salesforce should adhere to it soon. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address